# Python Clock Class

Tags: python, class

```
class Clock:
    def __init__(self, hrsIn, minsIn, secsIn):    # to create the clock
       self.hours = hrsIn
       self.minutes = minsIn
       self.seconds = secsIn 

    def SetTime(self, newHrsIn, newMinsIn, newSecsIn):
      SetTime = self.hours
      SetTime = self.minutes
      SetTime = self.seconds

    def GetHours(self):
      return self.hours 

    def GetMinutes(self):
       return self.minutes

   def GetSeconds(self):
     return self.seconds

    def DisplayTime24(self):
      print("The time is",format(self.hours,"1d"),":",end=" ")
      if (self.minutes < 10):
        print("0",end="")
        print(format(self.minutes,"1d"),": ", end="")
      else:
        print(format(self.minutes, "1d"),": ", end="")
      if (self.seconds < 10):
        print("0",end="")
        print(format(self.seconds, "1d"),end="")
      else:
        print(format(self.seconds, "1d"),end="")
      print()


    def DisplayTime12(self):
      print("The time is ",end="")
      if (self.hours >= 12):
        t = self.hours - 12
        print(format(t,"2d"),": ",end="")
        if (self.minutes < 10):
            print("0",end="")
            print((self.minutes, "1d"),": ", end="")
        else:
            print(format(self.minutes, "1d"),": ", end="")
        if (self.seconds < 10):
            print("0",end="")
            print(format(self.seconds, "1d"),": ", end="")
        else:
            print(format(self.seconds, "1d"), end="")
        print(" PM")
      else:
        print(format(self.hours, "1d"), ": ",end="")
        if (self.minutes < 10):
           print("0",end="")
           print(format(self.minutes, "1d"),": ", end="")
        else:
            print(format(self.minutes, "1d"),": ", end="")
        if (self.seconds < 10):
            print("0",end="")
            print(format(self.seconds, "1d"),end="")
        else:
            print(format(self.seconds, "1d"),end="")
        print(" AM")

       # finish the rest of this class method(function) definition

   def IncrementClock(self):
     self.seconds = self.seconds + 1
     if (self.seconds == 60):
        self.seconds = 0
        self.minutes = self.minutes + 1
        if (self.minutes == 60):
            self.minutes = 0
            self.hours = self.hours + 1
        if (self.hours == 60):
            self.hours = 0
        else:
            print()
       # finish the rest of this class method(function) definition

  def main():
   myClock = Clock(0,0,0)     # create a clock with a time of midnight
   myClock.DisplayTime12()    # display it with a 12-hour format
   myClock.DisplayTime24()    # display it with a 24-hour format
   print()

   myClock.SetTime(22,30,5)  # change the time to 10:30:05 PM
   myClock.DisplayTime12()    # display it with a 12-hour format
   myClock.DisplayTime24()    # display it with a 24-hour format
   print()

   myClock.SetTime(23,59,59)  # change the time to 11:59:59
   myClock.DisplayTime12()    # display it with a 12-hour format
   myClock.DisplayTime24()    # display it with a 24-hour format
   print()
   myClock.IncrementClock()   # increment the clock 
   myClock.DisplayTime12()    # display new/current time in 12-hour format
   myClock.DisplayTime24()    # display new/current time in 24-hour format
   print()

 main()
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong? It's printing 0's for all. I have no idea how my SetTime function should have in it but this is what it's giving out to me.

```
The time is 0 : 00 : 00 AM
The time is 0 : 00 : 00

The time is 0 : 00 : 00 AM
The time is 0 : 00 : 00

The time is 0 : 00 : 00 AM
The time is 0 : 00 : 00

The time is 0 : 00 : 01 AM
The time is 0 : 00 : 01
```

This is what it's supposed to look like.

```
 The time is 12: 00: 00 AM
 The time is 0: 00: 00

 The time is 10: 30: 05 PM
 The time is 22: 30: 05

 The time is 11: 59: 59 AM
 The time is 11: 59: 59

 The time is 12: 00: 00 PM
 The time is 12: 00: 00
```

Comment: Show what you have done to try and debug that s. Have you printed out the values of variables to verify that they are what you expect them to be?

Comment: I tried several thing with SetTime function, but I can't figure out what is supposed to be in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `SetTime` to assign the parameters to member variables like in `__init__` just above it:

```
def SetTime(self, newHrsIn, newMinsIn, newSecsIn):
    self.hours = newHrsIn
    self.minutes = newMinsIn
    self.seconds = newSecsIn
```

What you have now just assigns member variables to a variable called `SetTime` which is then discarded.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thank you very much bro